# New page after selection is picked

Tags: jquery, load

How would I set up a new page to load after the forced selection seen here (plus some delay time)? Basically, I want a new page to load after the user picks on the selections, with maybe a couple of seconds of delay in between. Thanks in advance!

http://codepen.io/mbng/pen/jWObrN

```
e
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can use `setTimout()` for delay and call a function for your redirect page. I have a litle modified your script.

I have

- Add `newPage()` function
- Get the `id` of clicked element
- modified your `draw()` function
- Add 2 seconds delay

Please try now:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbBaJG